# Developing google docs/slides add-on: How to make the Oauth consent screen jump in order to record it for the Oauth team?

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

Developing google docs/slides add-on: How to make the Oauth consent screen jump in order to record it for the Oauth team?

When doing in the script editor: run->test add on -> test with latest code->installed for current user -> It allows us to test the add on, but it doesn't pop up any Oauth consent screen.

Comment: What do you mean by jump?  Just record it when it opens.  Record your full screen.   Remove your consent for the app should force it to open the consent window if you have already consented you need to remove that consent.

Comment: Can you provide more information? As [@DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) says, once the OAuth opens for the first time, it is not necessary to grant permissions to the Add-on again. Is that not occurring?

Comment: Let me clarify: When you develop an add-on for Docs/Slides, you need to take a video, showing the consent screen, and send it to the OAuth team of Google. Now, during development, how do I FORCE the Oauth screen to jump after installation of the add-on in order to film it? In other words, how do I RESET the premissions granted, so the Oauth consent will appear again?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution: Need to go to here:

```
https://myaccount.google.com/security-checkup
```

And revoke the grant.